# Can I add RAM to my Linux system when it is hibernated

Tags: linux, memory, hibernate, hardware-detection

As far as the BIOS is concerned, when my Linux laptop (ASUSTeK Computer Inc. K53E, submodel X53E-SX806X) is hibernated, it is switched off.  There is no difference from a hardware perspective, unlike sleep mode where the RAM is still powered.

If I was to add RAM whilst hibernated, leaving the existing SODIMM in place, would Linux restore from hibernation successfully when I power on the laptop?  Would it recognise the increased memory size?

(A related situation is where a KVM/QEMU VM has been configured for memory ballooning, i.e. max memory is greater than current memory.  In this case, the kernel can dynamically recognise increases in current memory size.)

Comment: As long as you remove the battery and/or power cord the OS will handle such a thing just fine.

Comment: You're asking for unexpected problems if you do this, as, hibernation saves the system state to a hibernation file on the HDD.  By adding RAM when in hibernation, the system state will be different upon resuming from hibernation.  _It's best to do things the right way the first time around... power down the laptop, then add RAM._